# Raise ArgumentError When Argument is a Hexadecimal Representation

Tags: ruby

My script needs to accept only 'plain' integers, and raise an argument error in any other cases (letters, special symbols, floats, multiple arguments). Unfortunately, when the passed arguments is a representation for a hexadecimal like *0b1111* the script interprets it as an integer and accepts it.

Here is my script:

```
begin
  price = Integer ARGV[0]
rescue
  raise ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer"
end

if ARGV.length > 1
    raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (given #{ARGV.length}, expected 1)"
end

if price < 8
    raise ArgumentError, "the entered value has to be at least 8"
end    

if price.match?(/[A-Za-z]/)
    raise ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer"
end
```

Basically the solution I'm trying is the last block:

```
if price.match?(/[A-Za-z]/)
        raise ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer"
    end
```

This gives me an error: *undefined method* *`match?' for 2:Integer (NoMethodError)*

If I understand correctly *match?* only works with strings, but because of the first block the variable *price* is converted to an integer.

How could I fix my code and would *price.match?(/[A-Za-z]/)* even solve my problem or do I need a completely different approach?

The desired result:

```
Input: 0b1111

output: ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer
```

Comment: _"a hexadecimal like 0b1111"_ – that’s binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line

```
price = Integer(ARGV[0])
```

the input is already transformed into an integer if a transformation is possible as defined in the example in the documentation of [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer).

If you want to ensure only strings that contain pure integer values are transformed then you will need to check the format of the input string first. For example, with a Regexp like this

```
ARGV[0].match?(/\A\d+\z/)
```

that returns `true` when the input only contains digits.

Just replace the first block in your script with

```
unless ARGV[0].match?(/\A\d+\z/)
  raise ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer"
end

price = Integer(ARGV[0])

# ...
```

To simplify testing the preconditions I would change it to

```
unless ARGV&.size != 1
  raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (given #{ARGV&.size || 0}, expected 1)"
end

unless ARGV[0].match?(/\A\d+\z/)
  raise ArgumentError "the entered value has to be an integer with at least 8 digits"
end

price = Integer(ARGV[0])

if price < 8
  raise ArgumentError, "the entered value has to be at least 8"
end
```

Comment: What's about `ARGV[0] == nil`? May be it's better to apply `to_s` before `match?`?

Comment: You are right, that should be checked too. I would suggest a checking that `ARGV` has a size of exactly 1 before doing the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exception: false` key for `Integer` method

```rb
Integer(nil, exception: false)
# => nil

Integer("blablabla", exception: false)
# => nil

Integer("9.3", exception: false)
# => nil

Integer("9", exception: false)
# => 9
```

There is also `base` (second) arg in this method

```rb
Integer("0b1111", exception: false)
# => 15

Integer("0b1111", 10, exception: false)
# => nil

Integer("9.3", 10, exception: false)
# => nil

Integer("9", 10, exception: false)
# => 9
```

Finally you can use it such way

```rb
price = Integer(ARGV[0], 10, exception: false)
raise ArgumentError("the entered value has to be an integer") if price.nil?
```

Comment: The OP expects the input `0b1111` to return an error, but `Integer('0b1111', exception: false) #=> 15`